# How to reference an old assembly in ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework targeting) project?

Tags: asp.net-core, stylecop

I'm building an ASP.NET Core project (with target framework as .NET Framework 4.5.2), in a solution of a bunch of .NET Framework projects. I'm referencing one of the projects that uses [StyleCop.MsBuild](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop). However, when I do a `dotnet build`, I'm getting:

```
C:\MySolution\nupkgs\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.54.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets(101,5): error MSB4062: The "StyleCopTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
C:\MySolution\nupkgs\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.54.0\build\..\tools\StyleCop.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its 
dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [
C:\MySolution\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
```

Where `MyProject` is the project I'm trying to reference.

I've tried including `System.Windows.Forms` as a dependency, but it's version is 4.0.0.0 rather than 2.0.0.0, so that didn't seem to work.

Is there anyway to reference `System.Windows.Forms` to get this to build?

Comment: AFAICT the proper solution here would be to upgrade `StyleCop.MsBuild` to support modern versions of the .Net Framework / Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lionnnn stated in their answer, StyleCop as of 4.7.55 is [not yet supported on .NET Core](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/126).

I was able to work around this by directly including files I needed from the project itself as a link:

.csproj:

```
  <Compile Include="..\MyProject\MyFile.cs">
      <Link>MyProject\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Compile>
```

This compiled the needed files into my project without bringing over all the dependencies. Not the greatest solution, but this workaround is okay for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install the Nuget package, and the message was that it wasn't compatible with .net core.

My guess is that stylecop is not yet ported to .net core.

.net core and .net are not necessarily compatible with each other.

Comment: Fortunately, this is going to change with .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard